# Not able to use ImageIdentify

Tags: machine-learning

When I tried to use ImageIdentify (Trial version of Mathematica 12) on an image I clicked on my mobile I got this error message

ImageIdentify::interr: An internal error occurred: An unexpected error occured on NetModel["Wolfram ImageIdentify Net V1", "$DefaultElement$"].

Comment: Same error occurs for the example images that are given in the tutorial of ImageIdentify (ie. Hound)

Comment: Please check the ByteCounts of the model file data.WLNet is equal to that of NetModel["Wolfram ImageIdentify Net V1", "ByteCount"].

Comment: ByteCount of the Image I wanted to identify is 771730. So what should I do now?

Comment: The correct ByteCount may be 65353381, you just download part of the model file. So You Can `ResourceRemove[ResourceObject["Wolfram ImageIdentify Net V1"]]`, and re-Download the complete model file.

Comment: "...and re-Download the complete model file" How do I do this please? And what model file is this? I just want to identify some picture I shot on my mobile? Why do I have to do so many things to accomplish this?

Comment: are you using Wolfram Cloud on your model? or in an desk version Mathematica 12.0?

Comment: Desktop Trial version of Mathematica 12. Same issue in the fully licensed version of Mathematica 11

Comment: Yes, you can try my code above, and Quit Kernel, and Re-run `model=NetModel["Wolfram ImageIdentify Net V1"]` until you can get right result of model[image]. Your network enviroment is not so good to download resources from Wolfram.

Comment: Ran ResourceRemove[ResourceObject["Wolfram ImageIdentify Net V1"]]

Comment: Got this error: URLFetch::invhttp: A library error occurred. The raw details are: "libcurl error (56): Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92963/discussion-between-quasar-supernova-and-hypergroups).